# Message system or messaging system?

Tags: word-choice

In a reading passage in our ESL textbook it says:

> Kublai Khan made use of a fast and simple message system. Horse riders spaced every 40 kilometers allowed messages to cover 500 kilometers a day.

The exercise that follows on taking notes asks the reader to fill in the following blank:

> KK had a fast ----- system w/horse riders.

The teaching manual mentions "messaging" as the correct answer. What is the difference between "messaging" and "message" here? Is one better over the other?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the emphasis.

> A fast *message* system. [emphasis on the *messages*]

> A fast *messaging* system. [emphasis on the *conveyance* of the messages]

In the examples provided in the question, presumably the initial emphasis is on the messages themselves because the idea is newly being introduced. Once the reader is familiar with the idea, the emphasis is on the performance of message conveyance.

Comment: They both describe the same phenomenon, so there's no meaning difference. Syntactically, _message_ starts as a verb in one and a noun in the other, but they both get to the same place. This is normal in English.

Comment: @JohnLawler What in Britain we call a *frying pan* you call a *fry pan*, similarly *swimming trunks v swim trunks*, *washing day v wash day*.  Do these differences hold any significance? What do we call such an ...ing adjective - other than a presnt participle?

Comment: Clippings are normal, and their clips become ordinary words. Now that English is shedding all its inflections, you find them littering every environment.